# Amazon DMS not fully replicating Deleted CDC records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, cdc, aws-dms

I've followed all the instruction to the dot in the official Amazon User Guide of setting up an DMS task [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.RDSPostgreSQL.CDC)

My particular use-case, i.e. getting data from Amazon RDS postgres to s3, is for initial-load + ongoing change.

The particular instruction in the Guide are under 'Working with AWS-managed PostgreSQL databases as DMS sources'

Here's what the cdc records look like for a new record, where we update email and then delete it:

Op, id, name, email, address_line_1, address_line_2

I, 1, 'Sal', 'one@email.com', 'some street', 'some place'

U, 1, 'Sal', 'another@email.com', 'some street', 'some place'

D, 1,,,,

Here's what according to the documentation they should look like[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html)

D, 1, 'Sal', 'another@email.com', 'some street', 'some place'

So basically, rather than getting the before image of the row upon delete, we are only getting the primary key + Op

I've tried out everything I can think of at this point - but I've had trouble accessing replication store in postgres to see if deletes aren't being recorded in WAL or if they're just not being migrated.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer finally - putting it here in case anyone is in a similar rut - The replicate identity of the tables need to be FULL:

Here's the query:

ALTER TABLE table_name REPLICA IDENTITY FULL

Comment: hi, I am facing exactly the same problem. I tried altering the table to REPLICA IDENTITY FULL, after that though when I delete a record in the table, DMS does not create the S3 file. The table has a primary key id. Did you experience this?

Comment: yes @konkani we did. The issue was whenever the pgsql server was restarted, the replication process wouldn't work. We decided to switch our strategies and not use REPLICA IDENTITY FULL. Instead we have taken a more complicated approach where we have an intermediate db and we query from there to understand what the delete entry was for

Comment: thanks @Saljooq. going to research on another approach.

Comment: hey @Saljooq, I created a staging table which has "op" column which will have I/D/U values. Then using this table with MERGE query to populate the target table and then run TRUNCATE on the staging table. Are you doing something similar? How are triggering the MERGE run, is it scheduled at a frequency or run after file is ingested? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @konkani thanks for sharing that. I wasn't aware of the MERGE keyword and after doing some research that seems like the correct thing to do. We did something more manual i.e. we used pyspark to create ETLs which were fairly complex and did something similar to what MERGE and TRUNCATE would do and then some. I enjoyed using py-spark so would recommend in case there's more complex transformations up ahead