# Snowflake pipe, error when handling deletion record

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-dms

I have setup Snowflake pipe to ingest S3 files, which were created by AWS DMS migration task. The pipe ingests the files in a Snowflake table. S3 file with inserts work fine, but when a file has a record that was deleted, I get this error in Snowflake when the pipe tries to ingest it,

**NULL result in a non-nullable column**

The files are in parquet format. What am I missing or is deletion not supported in Snowflake pipe ingestion?

Heres the table,

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 name       | character varying           |           | not null |
 value      | character varying           |           | not null |
 type       | character varying           |           | not null |
 id         | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('constant_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "constant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "constant_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)



Here is the parquet file generated by AWS DMS when a row is deleted,

Op  name    value   type    id  created_at updated_at
-----------------------------------------------------
D   None    None    None    16  NaT NaT

If its a delete operation why does Snowflake need non null columns to be filled?

Update:

Followed the solution [here][1].
I have set REPLICA IDENTITY FULL on the table. Now when I delete a record in rds, no S3 file is generated by the migration task.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653720/amazon-dms-not-fully-replicating-deleted-cdc-records
```

Comment: Can you provide the details of the table you are loading the data into and samples of records that insert ok and ones that do not?  It sounds to me like a record that is a deleted record in the file doesn't have a value in a column that is set in Snowflake to be NOT NULL.

Comment: thanks @MikeWalton. We have contacted our Snowflake support, lets see what we get.

Comment: Your table definition shows `NOT NULL` for every column, yet a deleted record has multiple columns that are NULL.  That's your issue.  You need to change your table definition to allow nulls.

Comment: thanks @MikeWalton. So I removed the not null constraint from the Snowflake table, then the parquet file was ingested without the above error, but Snowflake inserted the row instead of deleting it. It ignored the Delete op in the parquet file.

Comment: Snowpipe is only used to ingest data.  It can not apply business logic based on the data in the file.  You would need to execute a `MERGE` after the data is ingested in order to apply that logic.

Comment: Aah, I was clearly missing that. Just read docs on merge, understand how to do this. Thanks @MikeWalton, one last question. In our current setup we have S3 files created whenever data change happens in RDS and these files immediately are ingested by Snowflake. Whats the best way to auto run a merge command after ingestion of a file?

Comment: Take a look at `TASKS` and `STREAMS`.  They aren't triggered by Snowpipe, but they will only execute `WHEN` a stream has data.